# Automatically execute script when launching a Linux VM from Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-marketplace

I'm trying to onboard a Linux custom VM on Azure MarketPlace. The problem is that the VM has default credentials which is not accepted by the onboarding team.

I have written some custom scripts which take care of handling the user matching when one is creating a new user in the Azure console, and it works perfectly fine. The goal is to deploy an Azure extension (CustomLinuxScript) but it can't be done automatically. I also wanted to use CustomData but it's the same issue. The user must explicitly install the extension in the portal, or use --customdata in the AZCli, which I don't want.

I would like the scripts to be executed during the provisioning stage. The solution template is a good solution, but before that I have to make my custom VM available on the MarketPlace.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the script during the VM provisioning stage, you can create the VM with VM extension both in [Azure Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2018-10-01/virtualmachines/extensions) and [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html). Then the script in the VM extension will execute during the provisioning stage as you wish, the execution is the same as in the Azure portal, but is during the VM provisioning stage.

There is a point you should pay attention to, the script must be no interaction. Well, I think you know it.

Comment: Hello, first thank you for your answer. But actually this is precisely the kind of scenario I want to avoid. Indeed I want the scripts to be executed automatically and each time a customer is pulling me VM from the MarketPlace. I don't want them to explicitly say I want to deploy this extension and so forth. I have already a Solution template which works this way, but that is not what I want to achieve. The customer will go to the portal and from there launch the VM just by clicking, and inside the script has to run regardless of the users' actions.

Comment: @moulip As I know, there is no way for VM to do that in Azure. And I think you cloud try to create a trigger to execute the script if create a new user inside the VM.

Comment: Yes I think this is the best chance I have. Thanks anyway.